# subtract and add between columns and rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some data look like this

```
id        date             total amount    adj amount
 1        2017-01-02         100           50
 1        2017-01-02          50           0
 2        2017-01-15          100          35
 2        2017-01-15          35           0
 3        2017-01-30          120           50
 3        2017-01-30         -120         -50 
 3        2017-01-30          100           50
 3        2017-01-30          50            0 
 3        2017-01-30          60            40
```

the output should look like, I have no clue how to do the subtraction between rows and columns.

```
 id           date              due amount
1            2017-01-02         0
2            2017-01-15         0
3            2017-01-30         40
```

here is my current code, but it only works on maybe 1 and 2 but definitely not working for 3.

the logic for this part is to find the due amount between each entry for each id. for example, id 1 has two entry, total amount 100, then he paid 50, so the adj amount is 50, and the second entry, the total amount is 50, he paid 50, te adj amount is 0. so id 1 due amount is 0 in the end.

id 3 who has 5 entries, first there is entry show the total amount for ID 3 is 120 and he paid 70, so the adj amount is 50, but the first entry is a mistake, so all amount revised. then the third entry shows the total amount is 100, ID 3 paid 50, so the adj amount is 50. then the fourth entry shows the total amount is 50, ID 3 also paid 50, so the adj amount is 0. and the fifth entry shows that the total amount is 60, and ID 3 paid 20, so the adj amount is 40. so in final, ID 3 due amount is 40;

```
select distinct a.id,
            a.date,
            case when a.date=b.date and a.total_amount = b.adj_amount then a.adj_amount
                 when  a.date=b.date and a.total_amount <> b.adj_amount then ABS(a.adj_amount + b.adj_amount) 
               else a.adj_amount
              end as due_amount

            from table a,
            table b
            where a.id=b.id;
```

I just wonder if there has any function which can do this kind of calculation between rows and columns.

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.  It is not obvious.

Comment: please let me know if the logic is still not obvious

Comment: "first entry" .. "third entry" ? There is no way to order entries in your table.

Comment: I know, but I just thought add entry number will make the table clearly. I just want to find the final due amount, but I have no clue how to do the calculation. it can not use sum, it is like subtraction between rows and columns.

Comment: How do you know the balance for id 2 is 0 and not 35?

Comment: Not quite sure .. Looks like you need kind of chains (100,50)(50,30)(30,0) and sum of last values of the chains.

Comment: I think, you should add a column that describes the orders of paid amounts. You're explaining that this is first, this is second.... however, once you insert the data, a user can't identify which one is first and which one is second. May be, on your date column you need to have a time stamp.

Comment: Main problem is that info about how `total_amount` get raised is missing.

Comment: for ID2, sorry for the typo, the 100 total amount should be the first.

Comment: and there is no order column to describe the order of paid amounts, I don't know how to add it, because the raw data is not in this order, I put the data in order for better understanding for this questions

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` and `SUM()`.

```
SELECT the_date, SUM(due_amount)
FROM tab
GROUP BY the_date;
```

Comment: i dont want to find sum, I want to find the final number for each id.

Comment: @yokielove you simply want the last row for each id ?

Comment: I want the final due amount for each id, for example, the final due amount for ID1 is 0, and the final due amount for ID2 is 0 and the final due amount for ID3 is 40.

Comment: @yokielove why is it 0 and not 35 ?

Comment: Ok, it would have been possible if you had a sequence of unique ids or timestamp.
But here I don't think that it's possible because, as the others said, you don't have any ordering

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work - if the transactions can be ordered.  Note that I've renamed some of the columns to help clarify their meaning.  I've also added a trans_seq_num column to indicate the order of a customer's transactions on a particular date.  I think you're looking for the amount that the customer still owes as of their last payment.

```
WITH sample (id, trans_seq_num, some_date, starting_balance, ending_balance) AS
(
SELECT '1',1,'2017-01-02','100','50' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '1',2,'2017-01-02','50','0' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '2',1,'2017-01-15','35','0' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '2',2,'2017-01-15','100','35' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '3',1,'2017-01-30','120','50' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '3',2,'2017-01-30','-120','-50' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '3',3,'2017-01-30','100','50' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '3',4,'2017-01-30','50','0' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '3',5,'2017-01-30','60','40' FROM dual
)
SELECT DISTINCT id,
       some_date,
       LAST_VALUE(ending_balance) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY trans_seq_num RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) day_balance
  FROM sample
  ORDER BY 1,2,3;


ID    SOME_DATE       AMOUNT_DUE     
----- --------------- ---------------
1     2017-01-02      0              
2     2017-01-15      35             
3     2017-01-30      40
```

Comment: can you tell me how to add the trans seq num column into the data?

Comment: @yokielove - Is the "date" column an actual DATE datatype? If yes, can you update the sample date in your post with the time component? e.g. SELECT TO_CHAR(some_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') ...

Comment: it is all the same, the hh,mm,ss all the same. all zeros. only mm/dd/yyyy has value

Comment: @yokielove - the ordering of transactions is critical - without that piece, I don't see a solution, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The others already said: you should have any way of numbering rows. Simple sequence will do the job. With such unique column solution is trivial, we only find last row for each id.

But you have no order. Here is my try which looks OK so far and may temporary help:

```
with q as (
    select table_a.*, 
           row_number() over (partition by id, date_, total_amount, adj_amount 
                              order by null) rn
      from table_a),
  t as (
    select a.*, 
           row_number() over (partition by id, date_, total_amount 
                              order by null) r1,
           row_number() over (partition by id, date_, adj_amount 
                              order by null) r2  
      from q a 
      where not exists (
        select 1 from q b 
          where a.id = b.id and a.date_ = b.date_ and a.rn = b.rn
            and a.total_amount = -b.total_amount and a.adj_amount = -b.adj_amount))
select id, date_, max(adj_amount) due
  from t
  where connect_by_isleaf = 1
  connect by prior id = id and prior date_ = date_ 
      and prior adj_amount = total_amount and prior r2 = r1
  group by id, date_;
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cd95450f7360fcb7090522f10c026a4d)</sup>**

First I eliminate *mistakes*. Subquery `t` does this, it is simple *not exists* with added `row_number` to handle properly multiple cases ( like (120, 50) => (-120, -50) and again (120, 50) ).

Data is cleared so we can recursively find connected rows by previous adj_amount = total_amount. We have to use row_numbers again to handle identical rows (60, 40) => (40, 0) => (60, 40) again.

Then only leaves are taken and finally max value of these leaves which should contain orphaned non zero value if such exists for each id. You can add `connect_by_path()` clause to see if connection works properly.

Hierarchical queries are slower than others, so if your table is big, be warned. Filter data at first, if needed.

This query works for your examples and some others which I imagined and tested. But even if it works you should add ordering column (if possible) and have guaranteed, simple way to obtain correct results.